# Incremental training using TensorFlowEstimator

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow for my machine learning model.

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
regressor = learn.TensorFlowEstimator()
```

[reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.learn.TensorFlowEstimator.md)

How to do incremental learning with model? I am confused about continue_training parameter in its constructor. It says you can call fit again and again with new data. And at the same time it provides partial_fit(). Please help me understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use fit() with continue_training; partial_fit will eventually get deprecated.